# Netbeans overflow color on the on code

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I really can not understand and I can not describe properly about this problem.

I use `NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201705191307)`

I provide a screen short below of this problem:

[image]

Comment: any one can edit this post for more explanation :)

Comment: Since this is not a common issue, I would guess its depending on the environment you are using Netbeans. First I would consider to switch of some features of Java here: -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true. Second replace Graphics Card drivers.

Comment: close and restart **Netbeans** it will be work fine after restart ;)

Comment: yes it work but something so much time needed to restart :(